# Nyquist Plot Stability with Angle

Tags: control, control-system, stability, nyquist-plot

I don't understand the solution done here. The Nyquist criteria I know is Z=N+P and I don't see the relation with this solution. Where do the angles come from?

[image]

Comment: Why have you apparently resurrected a question you asked on the 7th of August in which you asked: *I would appreciate so much if someone can help me understand the solution of this problem* <-- in your question above you ask: *I don't understand the solution done here.* <-- isn't that just the same question in different words? [Link to previous and now deleted question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/676792/nyquist-criterion-angle-change?noredirect=1#comment1802200_676792)

Comment: The deleted version was drawing more attention to the "argument & angle" definition. I wanted to post a clearer version since I understand that part now.  I also need an explanation as soon as possible. @Andyaka